# Exception: Jetpack Compose. Snapshot is not open

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying add compose to my current project. I only added a `ComposeView` with a `Spacer` in a recyclerview item inside a Fragment. Why am I getting this error?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Snapshot is not open
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.validateOpen()(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.access$validateOpen()(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.MutableSnapshot.apply()(SourceFile:7)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.applyAndCheck()(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$applyAndCheck()(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose()(SourceFile:10)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose()(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke()(SourceFile:28)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke()(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame()(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch()(SourceFile:9)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch()(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame()(SourceFile:3)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run()(Choreographer.java:856)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks()(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame()(Choreographer.java:603)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run()(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback()(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop()(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main()(ActivityThread.java:5421)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()(Method.java:-2)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: have you followed all the steps from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/adding)?

Comment: Yes. I did it! The exception log doesn't always happen.